# Temperature variation plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary, temperature

I have hourly temperature data from an old experiment. I would like to summarize the dataset into a graph in ggplot showing the mean temperature of each experimental treatment, and the variation in temperatures within each treatment every hour. I would like to have a non-excel graph that looks something like this: 
[image]

The data are linked here. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/27cft3118dha6xt/46_xxZZano

I probably have to use reshape to format the data correctly. JD refers to the Julian Day of the year and Time is the hour within that day. Note that labels A-H are treatment 1, I –P are treatment 2 and Q-X are treatment 3. Any advice on how to best go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: It seems [@Troy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2967665/troy) produced the whole thing for you. I was going to suggest starting with `dat$ts <- strptime(sprintf("%4d%2d%04d",dat$Year, dat$JD, dat$Time), format="%Y%j%H%M")` to get the timestamp which would then let you start working with the treatments as normal time series data and see if you could work through trying `melt()` on your own before continuing, but, you've got the full solution.

Comment: @I Del Toro Is the data removed from dropbox?

Comment: It is now gone sorry

Comment: @ I Del Toro Could you please edit the question and remove the link to a data which is unrelated to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
df<-read.csv(file="2011_Temps_obs.csv")

require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr) # for aggregation

df$Hour<-as.character(                          # load "Hour" in correct format
  strptime(
    paste(df$Year,df$JD,substr(
      formatC(df$Time, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"),
      1,2),sep="-"),
    format="%Y-%j-%H"
  ))

m<-melt(df,id.vars="Hour")                      # melt by hour
m<-m[!(m$variable %in% c("Year","JD","Time")),] # filter out un-needed columns

lookup<-data.frame(variable=unique(m$variable),test=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,8),rep(3,25)))

ggplot(merge(m,lookup,by="variable")) +         # merge m to get the test rollup
  geom_smooth(aes(x=Hour,y=value,group=as.factor(test),fill=as.factor(test),color=as.factor(test)))
```

This is the smoothed graph with CIs

[image]

**OR** this pre-calculating your own summary stats using dplyr

```
summdata<-
  merge(m,lookup,by="variable") %.%
  group_by(Hour,test) %.%
  summarise(mean=mean(value),min=min(value),max=max(value))

ggplot(summdata,aes(group=as.factor(test), color=as.factor(test), fill=as.factor(test))) +         
  geom_line(aes(x=Hour,y=mean),size=1,alpha=0.6) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Hour,ymin=min,ymax=max),alpha=0.1)
```

[image]